# Regular expression for no more than 1 zero in a row

Tags: regex, regular-language

I need to write regular expression for language {0,1} with no more than one zero in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex expression would be:-

`0?(1+0)*1*`

Since, there can be a single zero at the start, so we have `0?`, meaning it either present singly or absent.

The next `(1+0)` means, we see a series of (at least one) 1's followed by a single zero. This whole group of a zero following a series of 1's can be repeated multiple times.
And, we also add `1*`, at the end to avoid our pattern to always detect the required strings but always ending in zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found another expression **(1*01+)*0?**. How do you think, is it right?